# Any Open source Presto ODBC driver?

Tags: amazon-web-services, odbc, presto, powerbi-desktop

I'm looking for any open source Presto ODBC connector to connect AWS EMR Presto to Power BI desktop. Apart from Simba driver(magnitude) do we have any other ODBC driver that is open source. Appreciate your help! I have came through Teradata presto odbc driver but not sure whether it ll only support TD version of presto. Any insights on this will be great.

Answer (score 0):

There is no open source, maintained ODBC driver for Presto that I know about.

"Teradata presto odbc driver" is something that Teradata maintained in partnership with Simba. It is not maintained.

You can get an up to date ODBC driver for Presto from Simba or from Starburst.

Also, Tableau used to provide one, but I am not sure if they still do, and whether their version is up to date.

Yet another option is to use PostgreSQL's ODBC drivers with [Prestogres](https://github.com/treasure-data/prestogres) proxy for Presto. I never used that, so cannot comment on feature-fulness, your mileage may vary.

See more https://trino.io/resources.html#odbc

Comment: Yeah even teradata presto odbc driver link is no more available for downloads. I couldn't find this driver teradataprestoODBC64.msi for download but as per documentation here it mentioned as open source:http://teradata.github.io/presto/docs/127t/installation/odbc.html. 
This is for enterprise use so I think we ll pick from Simba. Any idea on licencing cost between 2(simba or starburst) on annual basis and which has good managed support.

Comment: I am from Starburst. Starburst employs Presto experts, including the Creators of the project and many top committers. This speaks something about "good managed support". Offer-wise, Starburst does not sell drivers alone. We offer more comprehensive support packages and products. See https://www.starburstdata.com/ and https://www.starburstdata.com/presto-aws-cloud/